# c# what's the point of type = new type()?

Tags: c#

Given:

```
myObject hello = new myObject();
```

What's the point of specifying myObject again in the second part of the line of code?

Would you ever do anything like:

```
myObject hello = new anotherObject();
```

Why not just

```
myObject hello = new();
```

Comment: I would find `var temp = new();` amusing. Or scary, if the compiler got it right... But seriously, I could like the short notation that you suggest.

Comment: How about `Mammal m = new Giraffe();`? Btw, you can use implicit typing in many cases: `var a = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();`

Comment: Considering something more C++ like even might be fun where we could just do something like: MyObject hello(params); That'd could be the equivalent of MyObject hello = new MyObject(params);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do

`MyObject hello = new AnotherObject()`;

if AnotherObject is a subclass of MyObject.

Comment: AntotherObject doesn't need to be a subclass of MyObject. As I indicate in my own answer, the only thing that is necessary is tha AnotherObject conforms to MyObject's type. Being a subclass is one particular case. Another possibility is that MyObject is an interface and AnotherObject implements it.

Answer (score 7):

Basic polymorphism. You can say myObject hello = new derivesFromMyObject().

Answer (score 4):

Given the possibility of object inheritance/polymorphism then yes you may at some point do:

```
BaseObject A = new ChildObject();
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you heard of polymorphism?

An assignment such as:

```
myObject hello = new();
```

would make it impossible, since you could not specify the actual type of the object being created.

You should not assume that the type of the variable and the type of the object that the variable points to are the same. That's the basis of [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_polymorphism). For example:

```
Vehicle a = new Car();
Vehicle b = new Bike();
```

In most languages, the object's type must conform to the variable's type. In most OO languages, this means that the object's type must be the same type, a subtype, or an implementation (cfr. interfaces) of the variable's type.

Comment: @CesarGon: while you are correct, I still find the question interesting. How often do you come across *real-world* examples where you declare a variable of a base type, and used the `new` keyword to create a specialized type? Not saying that the possibility should go away, but a shorthand notation like `MyType temp = new();` would probably take care of a vast majority of the cases. For the other cases, you would still be able to say `MyType temp = new YourType();`. Not me downvoting, btw.

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: yes, it would be convenient for lazy programmers. :-) But C# tends to the opposite, and make everything as explicit as possible (see, for example, the required declaration of virtuals and overrides). Other languages are different, of course.

Comment: @Fredrik: If you're creating a variable of an abstract type you **cannot** instantiate it with `new`

Comment: @downvoter: Please add a comment; you're not helping if you don't. Thanks.

Comment: @Cpfohl: of course, that is why the possiblity to say `MyType temp = new YourType();`, must still exist. But in the end, a vast majority of cases where you create instances with `new` are simple straighforward cases where you use the same type in the declaration and instance creation. However, the `var` keyword helps removing reduncacy here.

Comment: @Fredrik, absolutely, I don't disagree with you, you had just asked for a "*real-world* example" and I was giving you a very common one. :)

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but I don't like your tone. Supporting his shorthand new() doesn't limit allowing the long hand for special cases.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the problem with stating the type twice has been solved, only the other way round (using the `var` keyword) with:

```
var someClass = new SomeClass();
```

and yes, it is often useful to have a variable declared of another type than the actual instantiation, such as:

```
BaseClass b = new ChildClass();
```

or

```
MyInterface i = new ClassThatImplementsInterface();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Because this is how the C# language is defined.**

The specification of the type on the left side doesn't have much to do with the specification of the type on the right side. The specification of the type on the left side specified the type of the variable. The specification of the type on the right side specifies the type you want to instantiate.

The `var` keyword solves this issue, but the other way around from your example, so you can type:

```
var hello = new myObject();
```

Close enough I think.

Answer (score 1):

I've also wondered the same question.

In case we just don't use any kind of polymorphsm and subtyping, when we create and instanciate the object on the same line (like in your example), the A a = new(); syntax should be accepted...

We can use var keyword instead if we don't want repetition, but I don't like var on known types, it makes the code a little bit more complex to read.

Comment: You do realize that var can *only* be used on known types, right?  If the type is not determinable at runtime it isn't a legal use of 'var'.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say "Compile Time"

Comment: var was introduced to give ability to create anonymous types, like as output of a linq query for example. By known type, i was talking about "defined and obvious" types, e .g primitives types...

Answer (score 1):

You have the `var` keyword

```
var hello = new myObject();
```

It is the same simplification, just on the other side.

The use comes when you have a class hierarchy.

```
class Base {}

class SubA : Base {}

class SubB : Base {}
```

Then you might want to have the variable declared as `Base` even if you instantiate `SubA` or `SubB`

The following would not work

```
SubA hello = new SubA();
hello = new SubB();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myObject hello = new myObject();
```

The "myObject hello" declares the object.

The "new myObject()" calls the constructor for myObject... It's possible that you have several constructors that take different sets of parameters to create different flavors of the object.